# Xcode 6 – OS X Localization not working

Tags: xcode, cocoa, storyboard, localizable.strings

I'm trying to localize `Main.storyboard`, localization doesn't work.

I have files:

`Main.storyboard
|--Main.storyboard (Base)
|--Main.strings (Russian)
|--Main.strings (English)`

In russian `.strings` file I wrote something like

```
/* Class = "NSButtonCell"; title = "rus-example"; ObjectID = "0XB-XT-cHW"; */
"0XB-XT-cHW.title" = "rus-example";
```

In `Main.strings (English)` (for the same button):

```
/* Class = "NSButtonCell"; title = "en-example"; ObjectID = "0XB-XT-cHW"; */
"0XB-XT-cHW.title" = "en-example";
```

When I run the app on English OS, I get the same result, when on Russian.

I turned on `"Show non-localized strings"` feature in Xcode, it shows all strings as non-localized.

How can I enable localization?

Comment: I have the same problem for iOS app. Using Xcode 6 Beta 5.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? I have. But for me there is no option `Show non-localized strings` in the building scheme.

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but maybe someone else will come across this post:
I had the same problem for my german localisation. Running

```
plutil Main_iPhone.strings
```

did the trick for me. It showed up the following output:

```
Main_iPhone.strings: Unexpected character / at line 2
```

Even if this was a misleading error (the localisation file starts with a comment, that's ok), it pointed me in the right direction: there was something wrong with the localisation file itself.

Long story short: missing quotation mark or rather semicolon, but unfortunately you don't see this error within Xcode.

However, just run the `plutil` command on your localisation string files and check the output.

Comment: saved me this day. Thanks :)